# IUPAC name for a branched alkane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the systematic name of this compound:

[image]

My try: **3-propylpentane**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to take the longest chain first, i.e. the basis of the hydrocarbon skeleton is hexane. It has a ethyl group at position 3, so the IUPAC name will be [3-ethylhexane](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.11599.html).

Answer (score 10):

First of all, make sure to find the longest chain. In this case, it is 6 starting from top right carbon to bottom right carbon. Then, number the chain. You will find that the C atom bonded to the branch has the number 3.It is not 4 because the branch should have the lowest locant and so the numbering should start from top right C atom and not from the bottom one. So, the name of the compound is 3-ethyl hex-ane.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing to do is to be able convert the representation like those in your question to **line-angle** drawing and then number those carbons from 1 to the end in all directions. Try numbering then completely: For instance, you are talking about this compound. Then it helps to see where every thing is and where there are branches.

In other words:
[image]